# JXLS Transformer object is not getting initialized

Tags: java, jxls, jexl

I am trying to use **JXLS** with my custom evaluator for Excel downloads, following [this](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/expression_language.html) official page.

I have no clue why is it not providing me Transformer object. Trying to figure out from exceptions since a long time but unable to resolve it.

**Excel**:

[image]

**Maven**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java**:

```
InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/User/Downloads/ExcelTest.xlsx");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/User/Downloads/ExcelTest_Out.xlsx");

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is2, os); // this throws error and returns null object
ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = new IMCScriptEvaluator(ctx);

transformer.getTransformationConfig().setExpressionEvaluator(evaluator);
```

**Exception trace**:

> 11:23:15.496 [tomcat-http--35] ERROR org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory
>   - Method createTransformer of org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer class thrown an Exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
>   null  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory.createTransformer(TransformerFactory.java:35)
>   ~[jxls-2.4.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.imc.iss.web.report.impl.JXLSFiller.generateWorkbook(JXLSFiller.java:411)
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>    . . .
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   com.imc.iss.web.config.IssDispatcherServlet.doService(IssDispatcherServlet.java:36)
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.23-dev]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   com.sap.ui5.resource.AppCacheBusterFilter.doFilter(AppCacheBusterFilter.java:191)
>   [resource-1.38.4.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>   [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>   [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [catalina.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23-dev]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23-dev]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23-dev]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23-dev]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23-dev]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_144]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_144]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.23-dev]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)
>   [na:1.8.0_144] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jxls/transform/poi/PoiCellData$1 : cannot initialize class because
>   prior initialization attempt failed   at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiCellData.readCellContents(PoiCellData.java:88)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiCellData.readCell(PoiCellData.java:54)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiCellData.createCellData(PoiCellData.java:47)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiRowData.createRowData(PoiRowData.java:26)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiSheetData.createSheetData(PoiSheetData.java:28)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.readCellData(PoiTransformer.java:117)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:71)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:66)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:58)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     ... 106 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType
>     at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiCellData$1.(PoiCellData.java:88)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiCellData.readCellContents(PoiCellData.java:88)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiCellData.readCell(PoiCellData.java:54)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiCellData.createCellData(PoiCellData.java:47)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiRowData.createRowData(PoiRowData.java:26)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiSheetData.createSheetData(PoiSheetData.java:28)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.readCellData(PoiTransformer.java:117)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:71)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:66)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:58)
>   ~[jxls-poi-1.0.14.jar:na]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory.createTransformer(TransformerFactory.java:35)
>   ~[jxls-2.4.3.jar:na]  at
>   com.imc.iss.web.report.impl.JXLSFiller.generateWorkbook(JXLSFiller.java:409)
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   com.imc.iss.web.report.impl.JXLSFiller.generateQuoteBasedWorkbook(JXLSFiller.java:364)
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   com.imc.iss.web.report.impl.JXLSFiller.access$1(JXLSFiller.java:338)
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   com.imc.iss.web.report.impl.JXLSFiller$1.execute(JXLSFiller.java:168)
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   com.imc.iss.web.report.impl.JXLSFiller$1.execute(JXLSFiller.java:1)
>   [core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   ... 116 common frames omitted

Comment: this seems to be a dependency issue. Your code is trying to call a method that is missing. I looked at the version available, and I could only find one more recent version for jxls (2.4.4). If that does not work, you will need to do some debugging and some version digging

Comment: @Whitefret Could you please elaborate a bit for me to understand exact issue?

Comment: @Whitefret Also I can't find 2.4.4 version release news on official page.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxls/jxls/2.4.4 for the latest release

Comment: I have looked a bit into it. It seems jxls-poi uses apache poi behind it. Problem seems to come from a wrong apache-poi deps but I can't be sure. Try to import manually apache-poi to your project https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi, version 3.17

Comment: @Whitefret Thanks, You were right. Multiple versions of dependencies were creating an issue, would you like to answer the question? So that I can accept it?  :)

Comment: you can take the credit for it, you are the one that spent time on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Multiple versions of same Apache POI dependency was creating an issue.

Internally JXLS also uses Apache POI, which was also explicitly added into the dependency of the project, which had version conflict.

Hence skipping the JXLS Apache-POI and upgrading existing one with latest (As per need of JXLS dependency) made it work.